# How to prevent unauthorized users from connecting to Arduino BLE device?

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was looking at this BLE demo for Arduino:

https://github.com/dzindra/BLE-iOS-demo/blob/master/esp32blinky/esp32blinky.ino

I noticed that there is no "Authentication / Authorization" or explicit "Connection code".

The code consists of creating services and characteristics, and advertising them. At best you can see the following callbacks which are triggered when a client connects:

```
class MyServerCallbacks: public BLEServerCallbacks {
    void onConnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      Serial.println("Connected");
    };

    void onDisconnect(BLEServer* pServer) {
      Serial.println("Disconnected");
    }
};
```

I was wondering what approach people follow for ensuring that users can connect to an Arduino's BLE only if they are the owner (for example, pressing a button to "trigger" connection mode) etc...

On deeper searching I found :
https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/blob/master/cpp_utils/tests/BLETests/Arduino/security/BLE_server/BLE_server_passkey/BLE_server_passkey.ino

This other example shows how an ESP32 acting as a client would authenticate into a server:

https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/blob/master/cpp_utils/tests/BLETests/Arduino/security/BLE_client/BLE_client_passkey/BLE_client_passkey.ino

Both seem to be good examples for how two ESP32's could act as a client / server and authenticate each other. But then how would I get my iPhone to authenticate ? I use the following iPhone example for simply connecting without authentication.

Things seem a bit "hacky", and was wondering if there is an authoritative answer on how to connect to an Arduino BLE with authentication ?

EDIT: Basically, I wan't to prevent random people from just connecting to my BLE Device. I do not need anything more than that (I don't need encryption). I just want to prevent random people from connecting to my device, and breaking my smartphones connection with my BLE Device.

Comment: You can't really prevent the connection unless you want to use pin code pairing. You can build authentication into your higher level protocol once the connection is made.

Comment: @Paulw11 But how to prevent random people from scanning for my BLE Device and connecting ? Won't it force my smarphone to disconnect when they connect to my BLE Device ?

Comment: No, if your phone is connected then they can't connect (assuming your device suppprts only one connection at a time) A new (attempted) connection won't force disconnect an existing one.  If you aren't connected then they can. If you require bonding then they will need to know the PIN code in order to exchange keys and create the bond.

Comment: @Paulw11 So if someone connects before I do, then I can't connect to my device ? How can I use a PIN code to prevent other people from connecting ?

Comment: You would need to implement bonding and encryption in your peripheral. Exactly how you do that depends on your hardware. The other thing you can do is build some sort of exchange into your code so that after connection their is some sort of challenge/response between the app and the peripheral. If the challenge fails you can force a disconnection. Note that without encryption this challenge/response is susceptible to monitoring so it should be dynamic, not fixed.

Comment: @Paulw11 But I guess that if I allow people to connect prior to authentication, then people could just keep connecting to my device. Can you tell me what "search terms" I should look for so that I can find documentation on bonding for iOS ? I've been searching for a while and cant find any official documentation which shows how to enter a pin. Both the code examples from their website do not describe it either.

Comment: @Paulw11 For example, their BLE connection example doesn't require entering a PIN, and there is no other example which shows the whole PIN exchange thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209282/discussion-between-paulw11-and-kaizer-sozay).

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also looking into the same thing. In my case, i am using an esp32 ble(server) on my bike. My requirement is as simple as, I just don't want any random person to connect to my bike when i am not around. Please do keep us updated if you found any solution.

Comment: @androCoder-BD can’t remember. Got sidetracked by lockdown etc. Ask Paul.

Comment: Just to note,  my current security authentication is, after connection, I transmit a auth sequence and logging the time for reply, If I don't get the reply within time/get wrong auth key, I am just restarting the ble server for new connection. But this again, is not a good approach at all. :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems no matter what mechanism you use to verify a valid connection the problem remains that if your BLE device is actually using advertising packets to deliver data, then when someone trys to connect, until you disconnect an unauthorised connection the advertising packet transmission is interrupted.
I use a small window of opportunity to write a correct value to a register otherwise resetting the connection.

Comment: Do you use encryption to secure the value from sniffing?

Answer (score 0):

The function of the advertising is not to deliver data (in some rare examples it might be). Also, advertising has little to do with connections. Many devices advertise without being connectable. Anybody can passive scan your device, that's the point of the advertising.

Also, the terminology in BLE is peripheral and central device, client and server means something else, that is likely to refer to GATT client and server (where the server is usually - but not always - in the peripheral device)

About restricting the connection to your device: on connection you could check the MAC address of the central device and use a whitelist to decide if you want to disconnect. Even better would be to use pairing/bonding.